# Как сделать авторизацию пользователя с помощью заголовка Authorization в node.js?

Tags: node.js, авторизация

Как я понимаю:

Когда клиент в первый раз обращается к серверу, мы отсылаем ему сгенерированный *токен*, который сохраняем в сессии. При каждом запросе клиент отправляет в заголовке *Authorization* этот же *токен*. На сервере проверяем, совпадает ли *токен* из заголовка с *токеном* из сессии.

Это так делается?

Answer (score 1):

Да, описанная вами в вопросе схема иногда используется.

Заголовок `Authorization` может использоваться для [базовой авторизации](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Когда клиент присылает неавторизованный запрос, сервер отвечает со статусом *HTTP 401 Not Authorized* и заголовком `WWW-Authenticate`

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Some String"
```

Клиент в запросах указывает заголовок `Authorization` со значением полученным следующим образом:

1. Логин и пароль объединяются в строку "логин:пароль", логин не может содержать ":"
2. Получившеяся строка кодируется Base64
3. Перед закодированной строкой ставится метод авторизации и пробел, в этом случае "Basic "

Для пары 'Aladdin' и 'open sesame' заголовок будет выглядеть так:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

Вы можете использовать какой-нибудь готовый модуль, типа [http-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-auth) или сделать собственную реализацию.

Существуют и другие схемы авторизации, они описаны в [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11).

Comment: `Basic` авторизация и авторизация с использованием _токена_ это разные вещи.

Comment: Авторизация токеном уже описана в самом вопросе